# sed Regex to find name of database in USE sentence

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file:

```
Hi
USE dbname;
Hi
```

Which is SQL text.

I want to capture the dbname:

`sed -n '1,/^\(USE\|use\)/{/^\(USE\|use\)/{/^\(USE\|use\)\s\+\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\);/\1/p }}' 001.sql`

Edit: why I try to do here: Find from line 1 to line that starts with USE. In those lines, grab the one that starts with USE. In that line, replace all for dbname and print.

However, it says 'Unknown command \' (backslash before 1/p)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not just `grep` for `^USE `?

Comment: @anubhava Please show me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only wanting to extract, use `grep`, it was made for extracting things.

```
grep -Po '(?i)\bUSE *\K\w+' file
```

- `-P` option interprets the pattern as a Perl regular expression.
- `-o` option shows only the matching part that matches the pattern.
- `(?i)` makes the regular expression case insensitive.
- `\K` throws away everything that it has matched up to that point.

But if you want to stick to sed, you could do:

```
sed -n 's/^USE \([[:alnum:]]*\);/\1/pI' file
```

Comment: Thanks. Why doesnt this work: `grep -Go 's/^USE\s\([a-z]*\);/\1/' 001.sql`?

Comment: The `G` option interprets as a basic regular expression and you can't use the substitution operator with grep.

Comment: when grep says Output only the matched part, what would it be? Because in a Regex one would like to group only a part of the string. Is it possible to do without perl regex? (I dont know it)

Comment: Yes, I mean in the regex, how do you tell grep "Print only THIS matched part", which is a subpart of the matched string

Comment: So I must use Perl Regex, not possible on BRE?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep -oP`:

```
grep -oP "^ *USE \K\w+" file
```

OR this awk:

```
awk -F 'USE *|;' 'NF>1{print $2}' file
dbname
```

OR this sed:

```
sed -n '/^ *USE /s/^ *USE \([[:alnum:]]*\).*/\1/p' file
dbname
```

Comment: Thanks. Why doesnt this work: `grep -Go 's/^USE\s\([a-z]*\);/\1/' 001.sql`?

Comment: In the sed command, why it starts with spaces and not with USE|use? I found this is something I dont understand

Comment: It doesn't start with spaces actually. It starts with `^ *` which means match `line start` followed by `0 or more spaces` before matching `USE`

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -nE 's/^USE (.+);/\1/p' file
```

Output:

```
dbname
```